# How to add user specific unique id for a document in Cloudant DB using Java

Tags: java, cloudant

I have a document in `Cloudant` DB which is as follows:

```
{
  "_id": "9567e004dc1f1063f4e5cfa9471f5f6b",
  "_rev": "1-77c3cab7cc5ba63277843b4dafc6af42",
  "DocumentUri": "http://www.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?htmlfid=515-125EN&infotype=AN&subtype=CA&appname=skmwww",
  "username": "SKM",
  "DocumentDetails": {
    "ContentType": "text/plain",
    "Language": "en",
    "Content": "515-125 Price Change(s):Price change: DOORS Family AU price change  Today, 
  }
```

The `_id` value is stored in a properties file in my app. I need to know how to get the id name from my properties file, then assign it to document id in Cloudant DB using Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/) to figure out how to read a properties file.

Then you can create a Java Object with _id as a member variable, then insert that object into your db - the _id attribute in Cloudant will automatically use whatever you set the _id to in your object

```
public class Reservation {
public String _id;
public String name;

public Reservation(){
    _id = "";
    name = "";
}

}
```

And when you are ready to save it. This uses the [java-cloudant](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant) client

```
//Cloudant Connection
CloudantConnect connectParams = new CloudantConnect();
CloudantClient client = new CloudantClient(cloudantUrl,cloudantUsername, cloudantPassword);
Database db = client.database("myDatabase", false);

Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
Response dbResponse = db.save(reservation);
System.out.print(dbResponse.toString());
```